# How to store pointers to statically allocated objects in a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Lets say I wanted to make a vector of objects and another vector of pointers to those objects (I cannot use dynamic memory). The way I would do it is in the following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  int bar;
  Foo(int x) : bar(x) {
  }
};

int main () {
  vector<Foo> foos;
  vector<Foo*> pFoos;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Foo foo(i);
    foos.push_back(foo);
    pFoos.push_back(&foos.back());
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << foos[i].bar << endl;
    cout << pFoos[i]->bar << endl;
  }
}
```

I think this should work because `foos` stores a copy of the object, and then I store the reference to the copy (because the original `foo` will be undefined, so I shouldn't store a reference to that). But this is what I get:

```
0
36741184
1
0
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
```

The first to numbers from `pFoos` are wrong. Furthermore, the large number changes every time. I don't see anything that would cause this undefined behavior. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: But `foo` is not static, but local storage...

Comment: @rodrigo I thought the vector would make a copy of it?

Comment: And here is my reference for that comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right, you are saving the pointer to the `vectored` copy, not the original one. The problem is that of the mythagel answer: pointer invalidation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding items to a vector invalidates all previous iterators. Calling push_back on the vector may make the pointers you got from it previously invalid if the vector needs to reallocate its internal storage.

If you *knew* that you were never going to grow the vector again then this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  foos.push_back(Foo(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  pFoos.push_back(&foos[i]);
}
```

or as commented by rodrigo:

```
foos.reserve(10)

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Foo foo(i);
  foos.push_back(foo);
  pFoos.push_back(&foos.back());
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  cout << foos[i].bar << endl;
  cout << pFoos[i]->bar << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not every `push_back` will cause reallocation. Only when the allocated space is exhausted.

Comment: Replace "will make" with "may make" and solved. It is worth noting that calling `foos.reserve(10)` will prevent the UB.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was simplifying.

Comment: Both solutions work! Thanks guys. I'll accept in 3 minutes when SO lets me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not a good programming approach. The vector is responsible for storing objects and it may REALLOC memory to get bigger memory blobs ... So, your pointer is not valid anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

`vector::push_back` can move elements, which is why the addresses aren't valid. You can pre-load the memory for the vector to its final size by calling `reserve` before you start pushing things into the vector, or you can wait until you've finished pushing things before you take their addresses.

But you say that you "cannot use dynamic memory". `vector` uses dynamic memory.

Comment: I know that vector uses dynamic memory, but I meant that I can't do something like `new Foo()`. But thanks, I'll try reserve.